# Design of constexpr classes : merging constexpr and non-constexpr versions?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constants, constexpr

Consider a class that just wraps a value at runtime :

```
template <typename Type>
class NonConstValue 
{
    public:
        NonConstValue(const Type& val) : _value(val) {;}
        Type get() const {return _value;}
        void set(const Type& val) const {_value = val;}
    protected:
        Type _value;
};
```

and the constexpr version of that:

```
template <typename Type>
class ConstValue 
{
    public:
        constexpr ConstValue(const Type& val) : _value(val) {;}
        constexpr Type get() const {return _value;}
    protected:
        const Type _value;
};
```

Question 1 : Can you confirm that the constexpr version is designed in the right way ?

Question 2 : How do you mix both classes into a single one called `Value` that can be `constexpr` constructed or runtime constructed and whose value can be `get()` at runtime or compile-time ?

EDIT : 
Question 3 : If `get()` is defined in a `.cpp` file, and if I want `get()` to be inlined if it's not a `constexpr` what is the right declaration of the function ? Is it

```
constexpr inline Type get();
```

or

```
inline constexpr Type get()
```

or something else ?

Comment: `constexpr` functions can be called at compile-time or run-time.

Comment: I'd argue that non-static `constexpr` member functions are flawed in that they always imply a `const` function qualifier, i.e. `constexpr foo bar();` is the same declaration as `constexpr foo bar() const;`. There is no such requirement for non-members, i.e. `constexpr foo bar(T&);` or `constexpr foo bar(T&&);` may both accept non-const `T` (and it is possible to have constant expressions involving a non-const qualified class type). So be wary of that.

Comment: No, `constexpr` functions can be non-`const` because until the object is created and it's generated 'value' is in a `constexpr` context (either explicitly or put into a template), the object is still in flux and is susceptible to being modified.  It is at that point where the function calls used on the object **must** be `const`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just add the `constexpr` specifier to each of those functions that are potential *constant expressions*.

```
template <typename Type>
class Value 
{
public:
    constexpr Value(Type const& val) : _value(val) {}
    constexpr Type const& get() const {return _value;}
    void set(Type const& val) {_value = val;}
protected:
    Type _value;
};
```

You don't need a *const* and a *non-const* version, since that can be done by instantiating the template `Value` with a *const* or *non-const* type.

You don't need a *constexpr* and a *non-constexpr* version, `constexpr` means potential *constant expression* and whether the expression ends up being a *constant expression* or not depends on its arguments. Whether or not the expression ends up being evaluated at *compile-time* depends on the context and the implementation.

Comment: +1, just what I was gonna say. Even `mutable` is allowed inside a `constexpr` object.

Comment: Really nitpicky, but `constexpr` is a specifier, not a declarator.

Comment: @aschepler: Thanks, I knew it wasn't a modifier but I was missing the correct term.

Comment: @Vincent: Adding `inline` won't affect whether the function is inlined or not. If it's in a different _.cpp_ then it probably wont, as the compiler cannot see its definition from outside such _.cpp_

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Note: It is unnecessary to declare `get()` as both `constexpr` and `const`. The former implies the latter.

Comment: thought having two separate functions can still be useful, as constexpr functions cannot have static locals among other things

Answer (score 3):

Your `constexpr` class is designed correctly, except that you mistyped the name of the constructor (it should be `ConstValue`, not `Value`). But I'm sure that's just a typo.

Instances of your `constexpr` version can be used both as compile-time and as run-time objects.

```
template <typename Type>
class ConstValue
{
    public:
        constexpr ConstValue(const Type& val) : _value(val) {;}
        constexpr Type get() const {return _value;}
    protected:
        const Type _value;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x[ConstValue<int>(3).get()];
}
```